# css text formatting with various styles and sizes

Tags: css, text

I am having trouble determining the best approach to laying out a section of text/textboxes in the following format (image below) without using a table. This content would be located inside a div set to float:right; and would probably have various font sizes and colors.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.[image: screen shot]

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a `table`?  One could argue this is tabular data and therefore you would be perfectly fine in using a `table`.

Comment: Use a table.  That's what they're for: to display tabular data.  I get so sick of table-phobia.  Yeah, I get that it's bad to use a table for page layout, but come on!  Let's use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: You can use list ul/li..and do some padding/margin.
what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I have to agree, that this type of data is what tables were made for. Sure you can set it up table-less, but these are cells in a spreadsheet. Excel, cells, table cells... seems like a no brainer.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your feedback.  I figured tables would be my best bet... I just know how now with all of the new CSS tricks tables are highly frowned upon. I didn't know if there was a new fancy non-table way to lay something out like this.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using a table instead of trying to get fancy with divs and floats.